# .exe has triggered a breakpoint and exception thrown everywhere

Tags: c++, exception, linked-list

hope you're all doing well
im working on an assignment and i've been stuck here at this point for ages, and there are no errors or warnings in my code i dunno whats wrong. I'd appreciate the help
i checked all the pointers and null related things and still i couldnt find out what was wrong

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
public:
    int coefficient;
    int power;
    Node* Next;
    int getcoefficient()
    {
        return this->coefficient;
    }
    int getpower()
    {
        return this->power;
    }
};
class Polynomial {
private:
    Node* Head;
    Node* Tail;
public:
    Polynomial();
    int getco();
    int getpow();
    Polynomial(int arraycoefficients[], int arraypower[], int n);
    ~Polynomial();
    void insert(int coefficient1, int power1);
    void remove(int power1);
    double Evaluate(double value);
    Polynomial operator+(Polynomial O2);
    /*Polynomial& operator=(Polynomial& p);*/
    int degree()const;
    void merge(Polynomial p);
    void removeAll();
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, Polynomial& P);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Polynomial& P);
};
```

and this is the cpp for the header file

```
#include "Polynomial.h"
#include<math.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
Polynomial::Polynomial()
{
    Head = Tail = NULL;
}
int Polynomial::getco()
{
    return Head->coefficient;
}
int Polynomial::getpow()
{
    return Head->power;
}
Polynomial::Polynomial(int arraycoefficients[], int arraypower[], int n)
{
    Head = NULL;
    Tail = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        insert(arraycoefficients[i], arraypower[i]);
    }
}

Polynomial::~Polynomial()
{

    removeAll();
}

void Polynomial::insert(int coefficient1, int power1)
{
    Node* node = new Node;
    node->coefficient = coefficient1;
    node->power = power1;
    node->Next = NULL;

    if (Head == NULL) {
        Head = Tail = node;
        return;
    }
    //addition at head
    if (power1 == Head->power) {
        Head->coefficient = Head->coefficient + coefficient1;
        return;
    }
    //insert at head
    if (power1 < Head->power) {
        node->Next = Head;
        Head = node;
        return;
    }
    Node* temporary = Head;
    while (temporary->Next != NULL) {
        if (temporary->power == power1) {
            temporary->coefficient = temporary->coefficient + coefficient1;
            return;
        }
        if (power1 > temporary->power && power1 < temporary->Next->power) {
            node->Next = temporary->Next;
            temporary->Next = node;
            return;
        }
        temporary = temporary->Next;
    }
    //insert at last
    if (temporary->power == power1) {
        temporary->coefficient = temporary->coefficient + coefficient1;
        return;
    }
    temporary->Next = node;
    Tail = node;
}

void Polynomial::remove(int pw)
{
    if (Head == NULL)
        return;
    //only one node
    if (Head->power == pw && Head == Tail) {
        delete Head;
        Head = Tail = NULL;
        return;
    }

    Node* temporary = Head;
    while (temporary->Next != NULL) {
        if (pw == temporary->Next->power) 
        {
            Node* node = temporary->Next;
            temporary->Next = temporary->Next->Next;
            if (temporary->Next == NULL)
                Tail = temporary;
            delete node;
            return;
        }
        temporary = temporary->Next;
    }
}

double Polynomial::Evaluate(double value)
{
    Node* temporary = Head;
    double result = 0.0;
    while (temporary != NULL) {
        result =result+ (temporary->coefficient * pow(value, temporary->power));
        temporary = temporary->Next;
    }
    return result;
}

/*Polynomial& Polynomial::operator=(Polynomial& p)
{
    Node* temporary = p.Head;
    int pp;
    int cc;
    removeAll();
    while (temporary != nullptr) {
        pp = temporary->getpower();
        cc = temporary->getcoefficient();
        insert(cc,pp);
        temporary = temporary->Next;
    }
    return *this;
}*/

int Polynomial::degree() const
{
    if (Head == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Empty polynomial\n";
        return -1;
    }
    return Tail->power;
}

void Polynomial::merge(Polynomial p)
{
    int count = 0;
    Node* temporary = p.Head;
    while (temporary != NULL) {
        insert(temporary->coefficient, temporary->power);
        temporary = temporary->Next;
    }
    p.removeAll();
    return;
}

void Polynomial::removeAll()
{
    if (Head == NULL)
        return;
    Node* CurrentNode = Head;
    Node* NextNode = NULL;

    while (CurrentNode != NULL)
    {
        NextNode = CurrentNode->Next;
        delete CurrentNode;
        CurrentNode = NextNode;
    }
    Head = Tail = NULL;
}
istream& operator>>(istream& in, Polynomial& P)
{
    int num;
    cout << "Please enter number of nodes\n";
    cin >> num;
    int c, p;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter the pair of (coefficient,power)\n";
        in >> c >> p;
        P.insert(c, p);
    }
    return in;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Polynomial& P)
{
    Node* temporary = P.Head;
    if (temporary == NULL)
    {
        out << "Empty polynomial\n";
        return out;
    }
    
    else  {
        out << "Polynomial is:\n";
        while (temporary != NULL) {
            if (temporary->power == 0)
                out << temporary->coefficient << " + ";
            else if (temporary->Next == NULL)
                out << temporary->coefficient << "x^" << temporary->power;
            else
                out << temporary->coefficient << "x^" << temporary->power << " + ";
            temporary = temporary->Next;
        }
    }
    out << endl;
    return out;
}
//Polynomial operator+(Polynomial& p1, Polynomial& p2)
Polynomial Polynomial::operator+(Polynomial O2)
{
    Polynomial SumOfPolies;
    Node* temporary = Head;
    while (temporary != NULL) {
        SumOfPolies.insert(temporary->coefficient, temporary->power);
        temporary = temporary->Next;
    }
    temporary = O2.Head;
    while (temporary != NULL) {
        SumOfPolies.insert(temporary->coefficient, temporary->power);
        temporary = temporary->Next;
    }
    return SumOfPolies;
}
```

and this is the main

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Polynomial.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    int X[] = { 2,4,1,3,5 };
    int Z[] = { 1,2,0,3,4 };
    Polynomial F1(X, Z, 5);
    cout << F1 << endl;
    cout << F1.degree() << endl;
    Polynomial F2;
    F2.insert(3, 2);
    F2.insert(1, 6);
    F2.insert(2, 7);
    cout << F2 << endl;
    Polynomial F3;
    cout << "Here\n";
    F3 = F1 + F2;
    cout << "Here\n";
    cout << F3;
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Stream extraction (`>>`)  is not supposed to interact with the user. Consider what happens if you read 1000 polynomials from a file - do you really want to first enter the number of nodes and watch a bunch of prompts scroll by for each one?

Comment: You need to read about "the rule of three" and the concept of deep copies.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO it's the time you should learn using debugger.

But if I had to guess I would say the most suspicious part I see in your code so far is this instruction:

```
    return SumOfPolies;
```

in `Polynomial Polynomial::operator+(Polynomial O2)`.

With this `return` you cause the program to make a copy of a local variable `SumOfPolies`. However, you did not provide a copy constructor to the `Polynomial` class, so compiler creates a default copy member-by-member. This means a copied object, which shall be returned, shares the same list of `Node`s with `SumOfPolies`. But `SumOfPolies` will be destroyed immediately after, because this is just return from the method – and in the destructor if will delete all its `Node`s thus invalidating the `Head` and `Tail` pointers in the returned copy.

There are other mistakes and imperfections, unrelated to what you experience now.

For example, you create a new `Node` object in the `insert` method even though if may be unnecessary if `power1 == Head->power` – but you do not delete it, and the abandoned `Node` object remains in memory for ever (or rather until your program terminates).

You mix `NULL` and `nullptr`.

You also declared some variables where they're not necessary. For example in `removeAll()` the `NextNode` is not necessary at the function's scope, it may well be defined within the loop. You can drop the `CurrentNode` as well:

```
void Polynomial::removeAll()
{
    while (Head != NULL)
    {
        Node* NextNode = Head->Next;
        delete Head;
        Head = NextNode;
    }
    Tail = NULL;
}
```

You may also drop using the `Tail` member. As far as I can see you need to initialize or modify it in seven places of your program, but you use it just in two—and you can easily get rid of it in both of them!

- One is in `remove(int pw)` where you compare `Tail` to `Head` to check if the list is a single node only. Note this can be accomplished just by testing if `Head->Next == NULL`.
- The other one is in `degree()`, where you need to access the highest power node. But you could test the `Head` node instead if only you reverse the order in which powers are stored.
  With this simple change you would simplify nine pieces of your code! I suppose this is worth inverting direction of one `<` and two `>` operators.

Comment: take a look at the photo i put (edited the post), i have declared a copy constructor and still i have no idea what's making this code go crazy each time i use F3=F2+1;

Comment: You got a clear message: 'read access violation' when accessing the memory location indicated by `this->Head`. You use the `Head` member of the `*this` object which has not been constructed yet. What meaningful value do you expect to have in it?

Comment: Additionally, the code visible on the screenshot does _NOT_ copy the list, so–despite the new error you introduced by using uninitilized variable (Head)–the program is still prone to the error I described.

Answer (score 0):

You need a copy constructor that looks like this:

```cpp
Polynomial::Polynomial(Polynomial const& other)
{
   Node* head = other.Head;
   while (head != nullptr)
   {
      insert(head->coefficient, head->power);
      head = head->Next;
   }
}
```

When you provide a user-defined implementation of it, you should also implement the copy assignment operator, the move constructor and the move assignment operator. See the Rule of Five and the Rule of Zero: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three.